# How to I get the UTF-8 data into a QString

Tags: qt, utf-8

via server API's i'm getting contact information using member of  structure:

char displayName[USERNAME_MAX_SIZE];

One of those names is a European name with special characters: "Per Spånt"

the structure of the displayName is as follows:

[image]

When I import 'displayName' into a QString via the "fromUtf8" function, I am getting the following QString:
[image]

How can I get the correct string into my QString without converting the special character into two weird characters?

Comment: Are you sure the conversion is incorrect? That looks very much like UTF-8 interpreted as Latin1.

Comment: Well... fromUtf8 is the answer. It works for me. How about showing some code?

Comment: Gentlemen, my bad- I was "fromUtf8"'ing the wrong string !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, this is what works and doesn't work for me using Qt 4.7.4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

int main()
{
    char name[7] = "Sp__nt";
    name[2]=-61;
    name[3]=-91;

    std::cout << name << std::endl;                           // works

    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8( name );                    // does not work
    qDebug() << QString::fromAscii( name );                   // works
    qDebug() << QString::fromLatin1( name );                  // works
    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString( name );               // works

    return 0;
}
```